# How can I automate price high slider by moving right to left using selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have price range in my project. I can move min price from left to right. However, I cannot get how to move max price from right to left. Someone please help me.

Comment: Flagged as unclear. You should post way more details before we can actually begin helping you.
Some more info: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237 https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code if i am correct.

```
WebElement el = wMethods.findElementById("loanamountslider");
WebElement slider = el.findElement(By.tagName("span"));

List<WebElement> amountdetails = wMethods.findElementsByXpath("//*[@id='loanamountsteps']/span/span"); //Retrieved the amount splitups

    for (WebElement element : amountdetails){
        System.out.println("Amounts: "+element.getText());
    }

    Actions move = new Actions(driver);
    move.dragAndDrop(slider, amountdetails.get(amountdetails.size()-1));
    move.perform();
```

I tried with this URL http://emicalculator.net/

If it is same, then use this. OR just get the Slider element & move based on amount splitups either left [low] or right [high]